# Transfer money internationally via wire transfer, provided intermediary SWIFT but not intermediary account number

Tags: international, international-transfer, wire-transfer, swift

I want to send money from the U.S. bank to one of the Georgian Republic banks. Georgian bank provided me with an intermediary bank SWIFT but not an intermediary account number, and the banker told me that I only needed SWIFT.

But what I read online, the bank should provide me with an intermediary account number.
And It's a little confusing.

Is the intermediary account number required, or can I transfer money with only the intermediary SWIFT?

P.S. Of course, I have Georgian bank IBAN and SWIFT.

Comment: Not sure if you need the intermediary at all. I have never seen a form that even allows to enter such data - all they ask is the final SWIFT and account data